# Commutativity in rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can I show for every $m$ and $n$ in some ring and every $a$ and $b$ in the ring of real numbers we have
$$(mn)(ab)=(na)(mb)$$
since not every ring is commutative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $na$, $mb$ and $(mn)(ab)$ supposed to mean when the non-specified ring where $n$ and $m$ come from is finite (or, more general, has positive characteristic)? Also note that the word communicative is not the same as commutative which is what you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: The word is **commutative**, not **communicative**.  Similarly, the noun is **commutativity**, not **communication**.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks 

Comment: What? Do you want R to act as a module over your ring?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch you're right thanks

Comment: @PrinceM sorry I'm a beginner in algebra ,I didn't get what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean for $m,n \in \Bbb Z$.  Note that we can take $m,n \in \Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ without loss of generality, since $(-m)a = m(-a)$.  For a formal proof, use induction.  For the inductive step, note that
$$
((m+1)n)(ab) = (mn)(ab) + (n)(ab) = (ma)(nb) + (1a)(nb) = ((m + 1)a)(nb)
$$
and similarly, show that $m(n+1)(ab) = (ma)((n+1)b)$.

---

For a less rigorous approach, the idea is as follows:
$$
(ma)(nb) = (\overbrace{a + \cdots + a}^m)(\overbrace{b + \cdots + b}^n)
$$
and the product distributes as usual (as multiplication distributes in *any* ring).  In sigma-notation, we have
$$
(ma)(nb) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^m a\right)\left(\sum_{i=j}^n b\right) = 
\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n ab = (mn)(ab)
$$